# Copying shapefile to Feature Dataset using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, copy, feature-dataset

How do I copy a shapefile to a Feature Dataset?

Here is is my script.

```
import arcpy

import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/temp"

dataset1 = "C:/SDE.gdb/temp1"

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("scrap.shp", "dataset1")
```

Instead of copying the scrap.shp located in c:/temp into the dataset called "temp1"...it creates a point feature class called "temp1" in the root of SDE.gdb

Comment: I'd think FeatureClassToFeatureClass would be required for this.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing a variable with a string object.

```
dataset1 = "C:/SDE.gdb/temp1" #dataset1 is a variable
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("scrap.shp", "dataset1") #dataset1 is a string because of the quotes
```

Get rid of the quotes.

`arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("scrap.shp", dataset1)`

Also note that you are copying to a [feature class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/feature-class-basics.htm), not a [feature dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/feature-datasets/an-overview-of-working-with-feature-datasets.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `temp1` is your feature dataset, I like to explicitly define my input and output data. In this case, I am stripping the name of the shapefile and appending it to the feature dataset path using the following:

```
os.path.join(feature_dataset, os.path.basename(shp).split(".")[0])
```

Which, in your case, creates a file path to a feature class like so:

```
C:/SDE.gdb/temp1/scrap
```

---

```
import arcpy, os

shp = 'C:/temp/scrap.shp'
feature_dataset = 'C:/SDE.gdb/temp1'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shp, os.path.join(feature_dataset, os.path.basename(shp).split(".")[0]))
```